# Por que o input funciona no Python 3.x e não no 2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, input

Rodei este mesmo código com apenas umas pequenas diferenças na sintaxe para atender ao modo certo de *script* no Python versão 2.7.9 e também no Python 3.4.2

*Script* que rodei no Python 2:

```
name=input("tell me your name:")
print 'Hello',str(name),'!'
```

> ```
> root@hikerpath:~/Área de trabalho# python teste3.py
> tell me your name:joao
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "teste3.py", line 1, in <module>
>     name=input("tell me your name:")
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> NameError: name 'joao' is not defined
> root@hikerpath:~/Área de trabalho#
> ```

*Script* que rodei no Python 3:

```
name=input("tell me your name:")
print("Hello",str(name),"!")
```

> ```
> root@hikerpath:~/Área de trabalho# python3 teste2.py
> tell me your name:joao
> Hello joao !
> root@hikerpath:~/Área de trabalho#
> ```

O que está faltando no código que rodei no Python 2, para dar o erro de *string*?

Comment: Outra dica, ao invés de imagens do erro, poste o erro diretamente como texto, leia mais sobre isto em: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3635 Até mais ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu entendi, só que nesse caso, a imagem é do resultado, para provar que deu erro. o codigo em si está como texto. mas vou tomar cuidado com imagens da proxima vez.

Comment: Se clicar com o mouse e arrastar em cima do terminal vai notar que é possivel copiar o resultado da tela, exceto quando se tratar de layouts e GUIs. Estou escrevendo um dos motivos do porque imagens na maioria das vezes são ruins, principalmente pq muita gente não sabe, mas existem programadores deficientes visuais (acredite se quiser, eles usam leitores de tela e imagens são interpretáveis como texto para os leitores). Assim que eu terminar a postagem sobre o assunto eu lhe envio ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Justo e Perfeito!!! Inclusão é tudo! não costumamos pensar neste tipo de detalhe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) para ler *strings* no Python 2:

```
name = raw_input("tell me your name:")
print 'Hello', str(name), '!'
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nqbKXL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mqcikbqe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Console/RawInput.py).

No Python 3 elas são sinônimos, por isso funciona com `input()`.

Comment: Obrigado! @bigown ! Funcionou!